# Retrieve a user's First and Last Name, given its login name, inside a windows server domain

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-server-2003

Given that I am on a workstation, that is inside a Windows Server domain.
In my data, I have the login name of the operator who has created the data.

When I print a presentation of this data, I want to display the first and last name
of this operator, which may be logged on another workstation of the domain... or even could even not be logged at all.

Do you have any clue if I can acheive this, and how ?

In advance thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Win32_UserAccount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394507%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) WMI class, has a `FullName` property which sounds like it might be a possibility.

Maybe a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM Win32_UserAccount WHERE Name='username'
```

And then you can query the results from that query for the `FullName`s.

This MSDN page has information about using WMI from C++: [WMI C++ Application Examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394558%28VS.85%29.aspx)